# How to set a responsive background image in ionic?

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Im trying this

```
.pane { 
        background: url('../img/fondoapp.png'); 
        background-size: 100% 100% !important;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
    }
```

But using .pane or .scrollcontent repeats the background image in my others tabs, also when native keyboard comes up it resizes the image.

Comment: Could you please check the below answer ?

Comment: you want background on <ion-content> ?

Comment: yes, but just on the login

Answer (score 6):

First of all trick to fit background image to whole element is `background-size: cover`, Now you can make class like this

```
.view-with-bg{
  .view-content {
    background-image: url('../img/fondoapp.png');
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

Now add `view-with-bg` to `<ion-view>` of that tab and add `view-content` to that specific element (which in your case is `<ion-content>`) where you want background image. 
OR

```
.view-with-bg{
  .pane {
    background-image: url('../img/fondoapp.png') !important;
    background-size: cover !important;
  }
}
```

And just add `view-with-bg` to `<ion-view>` of that tab. This will be only applied to only that particular page. Plus here is nice [post](https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/) about background image tricks.

Comment: Ok thanks, but when native keyboard comes up it still resizes the background image.

Comment: Keyboard is actually resizing your content by coming up, that is why background getting resized. So you should look for that.

Comment: Plus if you want to change keyboard behaviour. 
1: install this plugin https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-plugin-keyboard
2: add `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);` in your `.run()`